# Input tag not giving correct output

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want is, on button click the sum of value in two input texts should be consoled, but for Any value for two input texts that I give, it always gives 0,0 as output, what am I doing wrong? And since both of them are 0,  their sum is also becoming 0.
**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WeB </title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="number" id = "num1" >
    <input type="number" id = "num2" >
    <button id = "add">+</button>
    <script src = "app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*JS*

```
let num1 = Number(document.getElementById('num1').value)
let num2 = Number(document.getElementById('num2').value)

document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click",function(){
    console.log(num1,num2);
    console.log(num1+num2);

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the latest value of the input on click of the button

```js
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function() {

  let num1 = Number(document.getElementById('num1').value)
  let num2 = Number(document.getElementById('num2').value)


  console.log(num1, num2);
  console.log(num1 + num2);

})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num1">
<input type="number" id="num2">
<button id="add">+</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the order of events:

1. You read the values of the inputs (empty strings) and convert them to numbers (0) then store them in variables
2. You bind an event listener to add those numbers together when something is clicked
3. You type something into the inputs
4. You click the button which

   1. Logs the values of the **variables**
   2. adds the values of the **variables** together

The variables still contain the values **from the time you read the inputs**

You need to move step 1 so it goes inside step 4 (i.e. inside the function you use as the event listener)